# Laravel 5.1 Form Request isn't saving data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

im trying save data using Form Request but isn't works.

Data return with error array or with success message but isn't saving data.

What's wrong with my code: https://gist.github.com/kneipp/42f7d316b9bbc2157668

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests;

class ProfileFormRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'intro' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}


<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Profile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Requests\ProfileFormRequest $request)
    {
        //$id = Auth::User()->id;

        return \Redirect::route('profile.edit')->with('message', 'Dados salvos!');
    }   
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant code inline

Comment: I dont see anything in the code you posted that even **TRY** to save data in any way

Comment: Laravel's `FormRequest` does not save data automatically and it is not designed that way either. It is for validating and filtering the form requests. You should handle save() and any other actions in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

you need to update your code to actually call the save method on your model which can be done various ways e.g.

```
public function update(Requests\ProfileFormRequest $request)
{
    Auth::user()->intro = $request->input('intro');
    Auth::user()->save();

    return \Redirect::route('profile.edit')->with('message', 'Dados salvos!');
}
```

Laravel Form requests are designed (amongst other things) to validate input and automatically handle redirecting the user back.

Also as a note, you can just use Auth::id() to get the ID of the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

Code refactor, thank you for Auth::id() tip:

```
public function update(Requests\ProfileFormRequest $request)
{
    Profile::find(Auth::id())
    ->fill($request->all())
    ->save();

    return \Redirect::route('profile.edit')->with('message', 'Dados salvos!');
}
```